# How to reference session variable in html when using echo ' ';

Tags: php, html, session, format, echo

I am trying to reference a session variable in this line of code

```
<?php
     if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
               echo '<a class="nav-link" href="URL">Sign Up</a>';
     } else{
               echo '<a class="nav-link" href="URL">$_SESSION["name"]</a>';
     };
?>
```

However can't seem to find a way for this to actually pull from the session data as it is being treated as a string and outputting literally what is there $_SESSION["name"]
Is there a way around this?

thanks!

Comment: do a print_r($_SESSION) and let us know the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: '.' is used for concatenation in php.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Ali';
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="URL">'. $_SESSION["name"] . '</a>';
```

This output the `session['name']`, which is 'Ali'.

As a result, your code will be:

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
           echo '<a class="nav-link" href="URL">Sign Up</a>';
 } else{
           echo '<a class="nav-link" href="URL">'. $_SESSION["name"] . '</a>';
 };
?>
```

Good Luck